# Enlarged partition of remote Debian server, now it does not boot

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, fdisk

I have a Debian 10 server (hosted on IONOS).
I increased the size of my SSD from 240 to 400 GB.

Then I wanted to increase the size of the partition to use the space.
I used `fdisk` to delete and the recreate `/dev/sda2`.
After rebooting, the server stopped responding.

The IONOS dev says that the data is lost. Is he right? Why? What happened?

Here are the commands and output before enlarging the disk:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 240 GiB, 257698037760 bytes, 503316480 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbc873d4a

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 503316479 502317056 239.5G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01: 237.6 GiB, 255135318016 bytes, 498311168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv00: 1.9 GiB, 2046820352 bytes, 3997696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop0: 63.5 MiB, 66527232 bytes, 129936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 118.2 MiB, 123973632 bytes, 242136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 118.2 MiB, 123973632 bytes, 242136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 44.3 MiB, 46419968 bytes, 90664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 44.5 MiB, 46682112 bytes, 91176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 63.5 MiB, 66531328 bytes, 129944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

After increasing the disk size:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 400 GiB, 429496729600 bytes, 838860800 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbc873d4a

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 503316479 502317056 239.5G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01: 237.6 GiB, 255135318016 bytes, 498311168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv00: 1.9 GiB, 2046820352 bytes, 3997696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop0: 63.5 MiB, 66531328 bytes, 129944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 118.2 MiB, 123973632 bytes, 242136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 63.5 MiB, 66527232 bytes, 129936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 44.5 MiB, 46682112 bytes, 91176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 44.3 MiB, 46419968 bytes, 90664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 118.2 MiB, 123973632 bytes, 242136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

This is what I did:

```
# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 400 GiB, 429496729600 bytes, 838860800 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbc873d4a

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 503316479 502317056 239.5G 8e Linux LVM

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 2

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): e
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 2
First sector (999424-838860799, default 999424):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (999424-838860799, default 838860799):

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Extended' and of size 399.5 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a LVM2_member signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 400 GiB, 429496729600 bytes, 838860800 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbc873d4a

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 838860799 837861376 399.5G  5 Extended

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.

# reboot
```

In something called the KVM Console within the IONOS UI, I see these errors:

`Volume Group "vg00" not found` (repeated many times)

`ALERT! /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01 does not exist.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current `/dev/sda2` is an extended partition, a container to hold logical partitions. Now no sane tool expects a filesystem or LVM structures directly in it.

You should *not* try to create any logical partition(s) now.

If you can use `fdisk`, delete `sda2` (like you did) and re-create it as a primary partition. Specify `999424` as the start sector (like you did). The new partition may be as large as your current `sda2`, it must be at least as large as your old `sda2`. The point is it should be *primary*, not extended; press `p` when asked. After re-creating the partition as primary, use the command `t` to give the new `sda2` the type `8e` (Linux LVM), the one your old `sda2` used to have.

If you cannot use `fdisk` nor a similar tool, maybe you can boot a live distro (like a Knoppix DVD) and use *its* `fdisk` to fix the partition table in question. Keep in mind the disk may be `sda` or `sdb`, or something else inside the live distro.

If you cannot do even this and all you have is e.g. a very limited environment of initramfs, there still may be a way. A POSIX shell, POSIX `printf` and POSIX `dd` are enough to "extremely manually" change the partition type to `8e`. Before you proceed, note that the command later in this answer assumes or bases on the following:

- The disk is `/dev/sda`.
- The type of the partition table is `dos` (it is in your case).
- You want to write hexadecimal `8e` which is octal `216`.
- You want to write to the right offset where the type of the partition is stored. For a `dos` partition table the respective offsets are:

  - decimal 446+4=450 for partition 1,
  - decimal 462+4=466 for partition 2 (this is your case),
  - decimal 478+4=482 for partition 3,
  - decimal 494+4=498 for partition 4.

The following command should work for you as-is, but other users willing to do something similar may need to adjust some values. The command is:

```
printf '\216' | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1 seek=466 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

(`conv=notrunc` is not really needed when writing to a block device like `/dev/sda`, it won't do any harm though. I used it in case anyone wants to use the command to modify an image stored in a regular file; in such case `conv=notrunc` is a must.)

After fixing the partition type, reboot. The OS should start normally. The next step is to extend the LVM structures; this answer does not cover this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I only have access to something called the KVM console. The command line starts with `initramfs`. How can I do this there?

Comment: @BetaCarotin Oh, ok, I get it. Is `fdisk` available there? Or is `dd` available?

Comment: It looks like `dd` is available

Comment: @BetaCarotin I think you can "extremely manually" change the partition type to hex `8e` by writing this exact byte (which is octal 216) with `dd` to the right place of the partition table. If the disk in question is `/dev/sda`, a command may be `printf '\216' | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1 seek=466 count=1 conv=notrunc`.

Comment: I was able to boot a Knoppix DVD and use it to change the partition type. The server boots now. Thank you so much for your help!